# With React+Redux, how should I store profiles in my store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

my react+redux app needs to store user profiles in the store. Example data:

```
{"user_id":11,"stuff":"more stuff"}, {"user_id":313,"stuff":"more stuff"},{"user_id":13111,"stuff":"more stuff"},{"user_id":21,"stuff":"more stuff"}
```

How should I be storing this in my store? I can reformat the data above if helpful?

I need store.profiles to store 1 or more profiles and it could include the current_user's profile.

I then need my Profile component to be able to find or fetch the current_user's profile in the store when the component render's. How should I approach this?

Thanks, I new to React+Redux

Comment: Do you need more than one user profile at a time? If not then just have a single key in the store to 'store' the one user. If you do and you need to find/fetch the current_user's profile use `mapStateToProps` (like you had in a previous question) to filter for the correct user profile.

Comment: I will need more than one profile at a time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were to design Profiles in my app, I would do something like in the code below. In this scenario, I am keeping users in an array. Alternatively you can use an object or [Map](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.html).

```js
// reducer
function userReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    // adding new user, just append to the end of array
    case ADD_USER:
      return [...state, {...action.payload.user }] 
    
    // editing an existing user, must check if exists! Othewise return original state
    case EDIT_USER:
      const filteredUsers = state.filter(user => user.id === action.payload.user.id);
      const isUserExist = filteredUsers.length > 0;
      if (isUserExist) {
        const updatedUser = { ...filteredUsers[0], ...action.payload.user };
        return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload.user.id), updatedUser];
      } else {
        return state;
      }
      
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// sample user obj
{
  id: 'unique-id',
  first_name: 'bob',
  last_name: 'jones',
  email: 'test@mail.com',
  photo_url: 'some url',
  bio: 'some text'
}

// container.js 
const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  users: state.users,
  getUser: (userId) => state.users.filter(user.id === userId),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  editUser: (userId) => dispatch(editUser(userId))
})

// actions.js
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

function editUser(payload) {
  return {
    type: 'EDIT_USER',
    ...payload
  }
}

function addUser(user) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_USER',
    payload : {
      user: {
        ...user,
        id: uuid()
      }
    }
  }
}

// probably shouldn't edit id
payload {
  id: 'uniquestring',
  first_name: 'momo',
  last_name: 'wawa',
  // ... the rest of the changes
}
```

This assumes that you already know the basics of redux. Otherwise, read [this tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/).

Comment: Thanks, In this example, where is userId being set?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I would create it in the reducer, using the uuid library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid. Once id is set on a user, you should not change it.

Comment: Note that generating a new UUID in a reducer is discouraged, as the reducer is no longer a pure function.  The code will run, but it will be harder to test and not work correctly under time-travel debugging.  Ideally, random values should be generated in the action creator - see https://daveceddia.com/random-numbers-in-redux/ .

Comment: @AnnaSm As markerikson suggested, the id is best generated in the action creators.